# How could I see all module's imported & defined functions in elixir?

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming

I have module

```
defmodule There do
  import Othermodule, only: [a: 1]

  def b do
  end
end
```

How could I get the list of functions `a` & `b`?

Comment: You can get defined functions using `There.__info__(:functions)` but I don't think there's any way to get imported functions. Why do you need this? Maybe there's another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: `There.__info__(:functions)` was the only information I found accross the internet. Let me ask another question....

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`__ENV__` macro](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#__ENV__/0) combined with `Module.__info__(:functions)` mentioned by [Dogbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/320615/dogbert):

```
my_functions = __MODULE__.__info__(:functions)
imported_functions = __ENV__.functions
  |> Enum.filter(fn {module, _functions} -> module != Kernel end)
  |> Enum.map(&elem(&1, 1))
  |> List.flatten

(my_functions ++ imported_functions)
  |> Enum.map(&elem(&1, 0))
  |> inspect
  |> IO.puts
```

If you remove the last `Enum.map` you'll get a Keyword List of `{function_name, function_arity}`.

Comment: Also: `Enum.filter` can be combined with `Enum.map` into `Enum.filter_map`, but I left them separate for readability.